# Search string from Encrypted Text in Sails JS

Tags: node.js, search, encryption, sails.js

I am creating a mail client in Sails Js. I am using bcrypt encryption technique to store my content in Mysql so that even I can not see what are the contents stored in Database like Whatsapp. But how can I make the search so fast so that it can it took text from search box and encrypt it and then find matched text and bring that email ?

Thank You

Comment: Why do you want to store content in encrypted form? If security, then what kind of threats you want to avoid is important to know here.

Comment: Because its a mail content. So much like Whatsapp who can not even see user message but still can search from that encrypted text. SO whatsapp is working ?

Comment: My guess is Whatsapp can't read messages on their server (encryption) and search happens on the app where message are not encrypted.

Comment: Oh I see...and what about Gmail ? are they going too high so we can not even think of it..

Comment: I believe, emails are stored in **un**-encrypted form in Gmail. (They are encrypted in [transit](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/saferemail/faq/))

Comment: Thank You very much...lots of doubt are cleared now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bcrypt` is a hashing library, not encryption ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms)).

It is not possible to get original content back from a hash. And it is not possible to search in it as well.

Even when using encryption if you encrypt say `abc` and your search term is `a`, only way to get `abc` as matching document is decrypt it before searching.

**Edit**:

Encryption methods don't have distributive property.

For e.g., multiplication is distributive (over addition) i.e.

```
a(b + c) = ab + ac
```

Let's say `enc()` is some basic encryption method then:

```
enc('A' + 'B') ≠ enc('A') + enc('B') // For most of encryption algorithms, otherwise breaking it will be much easier.
```

Comment: what about encrypt "a" before searching and then match with the encrypted text "abc" ?